# How to add an ActionListener in the child class for a component in the parent class in java

Tags: java, inheritance, actionlistener

I am programming a code editor in java and ran into a problem while trying to add an ActionListener to a button implemented in the parent class. The ActionListener implementation should be within the child class.

I have written the parent class DialogCreator and the child class ClassCreator this way.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class DialogCreator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    protected JButton buttonCancel;
    protected JDialog jDialog;

    public DialogCreator() {

         jDialog = new JDialog(this ,"title", true);  
         jDialog.setLayout(null);  
         jDialog.setSize(400,400);  
         
         buttonCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
         buttonCancel.setBounds(20,20,100,30);
        
         jDialog.add(buttonCancel);   
         jDialog.setVisible(true);
   
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    }
}
class ClassCreator extends DialogCreator{
    
    public ClassCreator(){
        
        super();
        buttonCancel.addActionListener((e)->jDialog.dispose());
         
    }
}
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new ClassCreator();

    }

}
```

Program compiled successfully and I expected to close the jDialog when I click on Cancel button. But nothing happened. So can you tell me where I did wrong. The ClassCreator is parent to multiple child class in my code.

Comment: Can you consider posting a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so this code could be run more easily?

Comment: Forgot to add this: buttonFinish = new JButton("Finish");
                        buttonCancel = new JButton("Cancel");

Comment: Just edit the question and include this

Comment: **Where** and **when** are you executing your `ClassCreator` constructor? if you provide this I could help.

Comment: @GrindingForReputation I have edited my question with a working code. Please help.

Comment: There are very few reasons to construct JDialogs manually when you can use JOptionPane's static functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake your making in your code is using `super()`. Remember that a JDialog waits until it gets a response before continuing. So your listener is added *after* you close the JDialog. So try using this instead:-

```
...
public ClassCreator(){
    super();
    buttonCancel.addActionListener((e)-> jDialog.dispose());
    jDialog.setVisible(true);
}
...
```

Make sure you remove `jDialog.setVisible` from `DialogCreator` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are attempting to do. The ActionListener should be added to the button when you create the button.

For a general listener you can write the code like:

```
buttonCancel.addActionListener((e) ->
{
    JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
    Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( button );
    window.dispose();
});
```